# How can I change numbers into letters in C#

Tags: c#, razor

I have code like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
{
<div>@i</div>
<div>@test[i]</div>
}
```

I'm using MVC3 razor syntax so it might look a bit strange.

My max is always less than ten and I would like to have a value like "A", "B" .. etc appear between the first  instead of the number "1", "2" .. which is the value of i. Is there an easy way I can convert i to a letter where i = 1 represent "A" and i=2 represents "B".  I need to do this in C# which I can place in my MVC3 view file.

Marife

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(char)(i + 64)` will work (65 = 'A')

```
for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
{
    char c = (char)(i + 64); // c will be in [A..J]
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd probably use the indexer into a string:

```
// Wherever you want to declare this
// As many as you'll need - the "X" is to put A=1
const string Letters = "XABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
...
<div>
for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
{
<div>@i</div>
<div>@Letters[i]</div>
}
```

I find that simpler and more flexible than bit shifting etc, although that will certainly work too.

Answer (score 0):

You could shift `i` by 64 (with a 1-based index) and cast your `int` to a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use i anywhere else you can do this:

```
for (Char ch = 'A'; ch < 'K'; ch++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ch.ToString());
}
```

Ah, just realised the last letter isn't constant, so you would need to convert a number somwwehere.

Comment: You still need to provide a way to do `test[i]` with your method.